# SGX enclave debugging

Tags: debugging, enclave, powervr-sgx, remote-attestation

I have built an enclave, now I want to use sgx-gdb to debug address in .so file.
I stuck here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8TvW.png)
What should I do now to get address inside the enclave? I'm so sorry if I ask stupid question

debugging the address